# Chart.js: get chart data from canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have several Chart.js charts that I may need to update at a later time.

Is it possible to extract the myChart object from the canvas element at the time when I need to update the chart? Or do I have to save every myChart object in the global scope?

```
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  createChart(i);
}

function createChart(i) {
  var $chart = $('<canvas id="chart-' + i + '" width="400" height="400"></canvas>').appendTo('body');
  var myChart = new Chart($chart, {
    data: {
      datasets: [{
          data: [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()]
      }]
    }
  });
}
```

Now some pseudo-code how I would like to update say chart 2 at a later time:

```
var updateChart = $('#chart-2'); // This is where I'd need to get the chart data from the canvas element

updateChart.data.datasets[0].data = updateChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random());

updateChart.update();
```

Answer (score 5):

ChartJS API actually offers the [`getChart`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#static-getchart-key) method to do what you want:

```js
let chart = Chart.getChart('chart-2'); // Select by canvas ID
// OR
let canvas = document.querySelector('#chart-2')
let chart = Chart.getChart(canvas); // Select using the canvas element

// You can now update your chart
chart.data.datasets[0].data = newData;
chart.data.labels = newLabels;
chart.update();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
    console.log(instance);
});
```

Update:
https://jsfiddle.net/furd1L27/14/

Comment: Using this "Chart.instances", you can get the objects of the created charts on the page.

Comment: Added a link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/furd1L27/14/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to store all data sent to chart in arrays. Once the array is updated you can send:

> HTTP/AJAX/SOCKET.IO

indication to the client, and update the chart.