# Playwright: How to get the chart data (Chart.js)?

Tags: chart.js, playwright, react-chartjs-2

I'm writing e2e test with Playwright and I want to see if each data is rendered correctly on the chart.

Using snapshot comparison is not the ideal case for me since I also want to know if each data is rendered correctly.

I saw in Chart.js library, it has `ChartJs.getChart('id')`. However, when I use it, it doesn't return the details.

And because the charts from Chart.js are rendered as canvas, I wonder if there is any possible way for me to read the data or to do visual testing other than snapshot. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js: get chart data from canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610376/chart-js-get-chart-data-from-canvas)

Comment: @hardkoded thank you for you reply. I tried the solution but it returned undefined.